# How I can attach downloadable files to my digital products via csv file (import) Bigcommerce

Tags: file, import, bigcommerce, digital

I want to import downlodable digital products to my store via csv file.

The files are already in my store, I added them via Cyberduck,so in csv file in Product File - 1  I added the names of files ( for example 26 Brazil Greece travel stamps collection.zip ) , and in Product File Path tab I wrote the path ( I copied the link from cyberduck), but still no result, the files aren't attached

Please tell me how I can do that

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add Product File - 1 and Product File Path columns next to category column and insert product file name like example1.zip and the link from the webdav